# orthogonal complement of a hyperplane

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a normed vector space, $f\in E^*$, $f\ne 0$, and $M = [f=0]$, which is a hyperplane. Determine the $M^{\perp}$.

By definition, $M^{\perp} = \{g\in E^*|<g,x> = 0, \forall x\in M\}$. My guess is that $M^{\perp} = \text{span}(f)$, and it is easy to see $\text{span}(f)\subset M^{\perp}$, but I don't know how to prove the other direction. Can someone help me with this? Or my guess is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $f(x)=0 \implies g(x)=0\; \forall g \in M^{\perp}$. Let $y$ be chosen so that $f(y)=1$. then $f(x-f(x)y)=0$ for all $x$ implies

$$
       0=g(x-f(x)y)=g(x)-g(y)f(x),\;\; \forall x\in X.
$$

Therefore,

$$
             g = g(y)f.
$$
So $M^{\perp} = [\{ f\}]$.

Comment: I see! Thank you so much =